# WHy can't I install MAVEN on my windows path?

Tags: windows-7, maven

I followed this >> https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

I want to install MAVEN on my WIndows. But it does not work. Though when I `cd` to the `bin` folder in cmd, it works. BUT when I add it to the path, it does not work.

I'm working on Windows 7 SP1
Java 8 update 92 (SE and JDK) are installed...JAVA_HOME is properly set and works

What is going on ?

Comment: Did you close and reopen the `cmd` shell after changing the `PATH`?